# Search Kit Actions do not appear on Form Builder form

Tags: searchkit, actions

I have a test search to select Contacts using Search Kit.  I have created a Table display (with the Enable Actions option ticked), and including a menu section containing the default links.  In the Preview, or if I view this display directly, I can select one or more results, click the Actions button, and I get a dropdown of all available actions.  The Links menu is also displayed against each result.

If I create a Form Builder form to display this same Table (plus an exposed filter on the Contact name), the display function works, but when I select some results and click the Actions button nothing happens.  The Links menu is also missing.

What am I doing wrong?  It feels like a permissions problem, but I am logged in as administrator, and have set the Form Builder form to require CiviCRM Administrator permission.

Comment: Do you have the shoreditch extension installed? I think its JS can interfere with the standard bootstrap JS used by SK and FB

Comment: No I don't have Shoreditch installed, though there are a fair number of others.  I suppose one of those could have interfering JS.

Answer (score 1):

Again, not really an explanation, but just wiped the first search and also uninstalled an experimental theme extension, then rebuilt the search and form from scratch.  Works fine

Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: that happens so don't hesitate to replicate on other instances ;-) it's also a kind of training

Answer (score 0):

not really a solution but have you tried to replicate on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/? I've never had this issue and your configuration seems right.

Comment: I've just tried to reproduce what I did before, and it works fine on the demo site.  I guess it's go back, wipe everything and try again - I was rather stumbling at the beginning, so may have left some rubbish around.